# Предложение с обособленным приложением

Tags: грамматика

Еще вопрос из тестов.

Из предложений 1-5 надо выписать предложения с обособленным приложением. В ответах дано одно предложение, хотя в задании говорится больше, чем об одном. Так вот, это второе предложение (которого нет в ответах и насчет которого я сомневаюсь):

> Почему-то именно ''Пара гнедых''
> Апутхина, этот сентиментальных романс,
> остался в памяти на всю жизнь.

Я считаю, что  ''Пара гнедых''  - приложение. Если я ошибаюсь, то насколько корректно дано задание?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь действительно есть обособленное приложение, только не "Пара гнедых", а "этот сентиментальных романс". Если бы было "Романс ''Пара гнедых'' Апухтина", тогда "Пара гнедых" было бы НЕСОГЛАСОВАННЫМ приложением, а не обособленным.

Мне бы отрывок  1-5 предложения посмотреть целиком, тогда можно сказать, что там и как. Это какой вариант в какой книге КИМов - Сениной, Цыбулько? Или вариант интернет-версии?

Comment: Людмила, в первом предложении приложения нет, это точно. В ответе дано это предложение: Сначала это были песни, ими битком была набита память бабушки, купеческой дочки, иркутской интеллигентки, медсестры в русско-японскую, преподавательницы Пансиона благородных девиц, учительницы сельской школы после революции. Ну здесь и так ясно, что приложение есть.

Comment: Это из книги: ЕГЭ. Русский язык.  Типовые задания с решениями. Н.М. Девятова, Е.Ю. Геймбук. - М. : Проспект, 2011.

Comment: В ответе верно, конечно, но и во втором тоже есть. В этой книге много ошибок и некорректных заданий. Лучше решать по  Цыбулько или Сениной.Если хотите, напишите на почту l_shepeleva@mail.ru  , я пришлю интернет-вариант

Comment: Да, Людмила, в ответе верно. Сомнения возникли из-за второго предложения. но вы развеяли: я оказалась права. Спасибо.